# (javascript) why do i need to use a wrap function for event handlers?

Tags: javascript, closures, event-handling, wrap-function

I'm trying to understand why in the following code I need Dragger.prototype.wrap and why I can't just use the event handling methods directly:

```
function Dragger(id) {
    this.isMouseDown = false;
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    this.element.onmousedown = this.wrap(this, "mouseDown");
}

Dragger.prototype.wrap = function(obj, method) {
    return function(event) {
        obj[method](event);
    }
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseDown = function(event) {
    this.oldMoveHandler = document.body.onmousemove;
    document.onmousemove = this.wrap(this, "mouseMove");
    this.oldUpHandler = document.body.onmousemove;
    document.onmouseup = this.wrap(this, "mouseUp");
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
    this.isMouseDown = true;
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseMove = function(event) {
    if (!this.isMouseDown) {
        return;
    }
    this.element.style.left = (this.element.offsetLeft
            + (event.clientX - this.oldX)) + "px";
    this.element.style.top = (this.element.offsetTop
            + (event.clientY - this.oldY)) + "px";
    this.oldX = event.clientX;
    this.oldY = event.clientY;
}

Dragger.prototype.mouseUp = function(event) {
    this.isMouseDown = false;
    document.onmousemove = this.oldMoveHandler;
    document.onmouseup = this.oldUpHandler;
}
```

I'm told it's because `this` changes without it, but I don't understand why `this` changes, why the wrap function prevents it from changing, and what `this` would change to without the wrap function.

Comment: Your title implies a different question than the content of your question.  Do you want to know about event handlers, the value of `this` in a given scope, or class definition with `prototype`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap them because when a function is used as an event handler, the `this` keyword refers to the DOM element that triggered the event, and if you don't wrap it, you don't have access to the instance members of your `Dragger` object, like `this.isMouseDown`.

For example:

Let's say you have a button:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonId" value="Click me" />
```

And you have the following object:

```
var obj = {
  value: 'I am an object member',
  method: function () {
    alert(this.value);
  }
}
```

If you call:

```
obj.method();
```

You will see an alert with the text contained in the `value` member of the `obj` object (*'I am an object member'*).

If you use the `obj.method` function as an event handler:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = obj.method;
```

When the user clicks the button, it will alert *'Click me'*.

Why?
Because when the click event is fired, `obj.method` will be executed with the `this` keyword pointing to the DOM element, and it will alert *'Click me'* because the button contains a `value` member.

You can check the above snippets running [here](http://jsbin.com/epixi).

---

For context enforcement, I always keep close a [bind](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) function:

```
// The .bind method from Prototype.js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
             object = args.shift();
    return function(){
      return fn.apply(object,
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
  };
}
```

It allows you to wrap any function, enforcing the context. As the first argument, it receives the object that will be used as `this`, and the rest of optional arguments, are the ones the wrapped functionenter code here will be called with.

In the button example we could use it as :

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = obj.method.bind(obj);
```

It's really helpful in a lot of situations and it will be introduced as part of ECMAScript 5.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate? i don't understand.

Comment: ah, so the difference is that 'this' will refer to the DOM object itself, and not to the handler (and thus I couldn't access things like this.isMouseDown since a <div> doesn't have isMouseDown but my class Dragger does?)

Comment: @hatorade: Exactly, you got it.

Comment: and it's because of closure that the method declared in the object gets the object 'this' because it keeps the environment it was made in?

Comment: I think it may have been confusing to see the object literal instead of an instantiated object.

Comment: @hatorade Yes, closure wins again.

Comment: ooh ok i think i get it - the wrap takes 'this' as the object is declared (refers to the object) and creates the method mouseDown, and the wrap keeps 'this' referring to the object because of closure. then, since everything else is called through mouseDown, 'this' always refers to the same object that was initially referenced. correct?

Comment: @hatorade: Correct, `wrap` returns a new function that remembers (thanks to the outer closure) `this` which it's being passed as the `obj` argument.

Answer (score 3):

[CMS gave a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768578/javascript-why-do-i-need-to-use-a-wrap-function-for-event-handlers/1768603#1768603) about the value of `this` in different contexts.  But as a side note, here's a handy function that you can use to generalize the effect of `Dragger.wrap` (which is similar to `dojo.hitch`) if you're not using a library or using a library that doesn't have such a tool:

```
var lockContext = function(context, callback) {
    return function() {
        callback.apply(context, arguments);
    }
};
```